# Why does reputation start at 1, and have a lower bound of 1?

Tags: discussion, reputation

If a user is the type of person to consecutively get downvoted to potential negative reputation, so be it. What's the reasoning to maintain a minimum of one?

One reason that may justify this is of trying to not deter new users from the site who haven't read the FAQ and unknowingly and wrongly ask or answer a question. But most of us acknowledge this and not downvote in such a scenario.

So what's the reasoning behind this lower bound of 1?

Comment: I think about it like this: You earn one reputation point for creating the account. Then you get the ask/answer privilege for that, which non-users (0 points) don't have: https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/create-posts

Comment: @FabianRöling Good thinking! I would agree with that statement.

Answer (score 109, accepted):

> The StackOverflow team believes that everybody's special in their own way and doesn't deserve to have a negative self-esteem (aka reputation). <sup>[(ref)](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/2624/137826)</sup>

This. A rep of zero or negative seemed cruel.

Plus, everyone starts out as "a one" instead of "a zero".

Comment: Oh, the irony. I would've thought it would have been my serious one, not one of my silly ones. Goes to show you: Truth is sometimes exactly the same as fiction.

Comment: That's what I call... "propaganda". lol!

Comment: Rose West, she doesn't need negative self-esteem?

Comment: Yeah, say No to cruelty against animals! :-) But what if new member asks question, gets 20 downvotes. Then asks another question, gets 2 upvotes. Will he still be at 1? It doesn't seem fair if those first downvotes are just ignored. Then again, it seems to be some kind of "forgiveness" factor.

Comment: Still, as Delphi/C++ developer, I hate 1-bound ranges! All ranges should start at 0! :-)

Comment: @Tom - as a Gloucester local, I call bad taste!

Comment: Note: I have always had a first rep score of -2, making my rep graph (http://stackoverflow.com/users/6309?tab=reputationhistory#tab-top) displaying rep from -10000 (!) up to my current score...

Comment: @VonC did they fix that?

Comment: @CodeBlend yes: my rep doesn't show that initial -2 anymore, plus they changed the graph.

Comment: Really? Why not do that with questions and answers as well? Don't negative scores on questions or answers discourage the questioner or  from asking or answering? (I know it doesn't, but I was just trying to get an analogy to your point...)

Comment: Why is reputation related to "self-esteem" though. I never think of it as such and never will. Any kind of attention to "self-esteem" does much more bad than good to all of us.

Comment: Did they change something because my reputation is -200.

Answer (score 141):

I'm going to add one other reason:

If there were negative scores, then some kinds of people would try for the *most negative* score.  And that wouldn't be good for Stack Overflow.

Comment: I'd upvote this if I could. It wouldn't be fun, but it *would* be FASCINATING!

Comment: There are negative scores for questions and answers. I haven't seen a person in the race to get most negative votes...

Comment: @AwalGarg http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/326492/shop-system-reputation-points-buyable-for-real-currency

Comment: They would rapidly be banned.

Comment: @Raedwald it seems to me implied that such a contest would have a *without/before getting banned* side-condition. Just like the people who use roadside "your speed is [,,,]" signs to see who can get the largest number - it's implied that this is without crashing and/or before the police arrive. In that case I believe most such signs are now designed in a way that they refuse to display numbers that would win such a competition, so that when they reach the point the sign refuses to show a number they give up and do something less dangerous rather than trying for even faster speeds.

Answer (score 105):

I don't know the real reason, so I'll wildly speculate:

1. Jon Skeet forced them to use an unsigned int.
2. So nobody just creates another account if their rep went below the starting point (1). This cuts down on a bunch of zombie accounts.
3. The StackOverflow team believes that everybody's special in their own way and doesn't deserve to have a negative self-esteem (aka reputation).

Choose whichever explanation you find best suits you.

Comment: I think #2 is most likely, though I do like #1 and #3 :-)

Comment: I'll go for #1 :P

Comment: ... #3 For The Win

Comment: An unsigned int would start at 0, not 1.

Comment: @joe-z at which point the fencepost handler kicks in and increments it one.

Answer (score 20):

Because:

- `0` reputation seems a bit demoralizing as opposed to `1` reputation
- It would encourage people who drop below `1` reputation to simply start a new account
- Seeing that everyone hates you might discourage you from returning to the site

Comment: I accept point 1 and 2. But do we really need the users those user from point 3? Note that I don't mean those who dipped into the negatives and then got there act together again.

Comment: 0 seems 'demoralizing' for developers? I find that doubtful, personally I would take it as an indication that someone was just a newbie to the site. Maybe you're referring to repeatedly hitting 0 rep due to down votes, but if that is deserved so be it - too much PC in the world nowadays!

Comment: The third point draws a bit of suspicion: Wouldn't one be discouraged anyway from a post being heavily downvoted, deleted, or closed?

Comment: I was a *bit* discouraged at first; my formatting was *terrible*, I was in a bit of a tizzy. I thought everybody hates me here, but then I saw that just *maybe* most of us are actually quite nice :)

Comment: My first Stack Exchange post got a downvote. Having a negative reputation would have made me not contribute at all to Stack Exchange