# Why isn't a negative reputation applied in SO?

Tags: discussion, reputation

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why does reputation have a lower bound of 1?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2621/why-does-reputation-have-a-lower-bound-of-1)

Hi,

I have noticed that if a user with 1 vote gets down voted for any of his questions or answers his vote count remains the same. After some time when he get up voted the points for the down votes are not counted? If he gets 1 up vote his reputation goes to 11 instead of 9.

Why this happens?

Is this intentional or a bug?

Answer (score 1):

This is by design. I believe Jeff said that it "seemed cruel" to have less than 1 reputation.

Here's that question: [Why does reputation have a lower bound of 1?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2621/why-does-reputation-have-a-lower-bound-of-1)