# Can reputation point be minus?

Tags: discussion, reputation

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why does reputation have a lower bound of 1?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2621/why-does-reputation-have-a-lower-bound-of-1)
>   [Why isn't a negative reputation applied in SO?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4436/why-isnt-a-negative-reputation-applied-in-so)

New user who has 1 reputation point.He or she asked a question then other users down-vote his/her question.Can his/her reputation be minus? If not, why?

Comment: Already three downvotes, I guess someone is willing to try out!

Comment: I'm afraid to ask question :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No.

Reputation is there to give incentive and reward users.  A negative reputation would be the opposite of an incentive - it would be a sort of punishment.

As [someone](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/2625/172936) once said -

> The StackOverflow team believes that everybody's special in their own way and doesn't deserve to have a negative self-esteem (aka reputation).