# Reputation count

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, reputation, new-users

I just made my first post and it got down voted.

reputation = -2

Then I selected a best answer, earned +2 rep for it.

reputation = 3 but technically it should be 0 (or 1 if they don't like zeroes)

Now look at my recent page. All time reputation earned = 8. But at top it shows 11.
see this:

> https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/recent/134258

Comment: We can't see your recent page btw.

Comment: @Warrior: See here: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2621/why-does-reputation-have-a-lower-bound-of-1

Comment: oooo, but I can!

Comment: Maybe I can too, but you just don't know....

Comment: @balpha a few sec ago it showed 3 instead of 1. That's a bug for sure.

Comment: okay, see my recent page. All time reputation earned = 8. But at top it shows 11.

Comment: @Diago you should have cross checked the bug first.

Comment: Re-opened. However I suspect it's a caching issue.

Comment: Yeah, that's been around for a while. If you click one of the other tabs on your "recent" page (reputation, responses, etc.) and then back to the "summary" tab, you've got the right number.

Comment: @diago I saw it just after choosing the best answer, so certainly not a caching issue.

Comment: @balpha I still see wrong numbers there. 18 and 21.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that's how it will be for the whole day.  But 3 rep is nothing to worry about.

Answer (score 3):

You can't go negative.  It sometimes causes interesting bugs.  But the possible rep to be gained by any exploit is very minimal, and thus, I'd say, not important enough to fix.