# Appropriate data type for reputation points

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, reputation

There seems to be a "rounding error" on the reputation count. I have just been awarded 100 points for associating my stack overflow account, yet total points reads 101. Same happens on stack overflow. Not a big thing, but we should look like decent programmers to banks too.

Comment: `[status-bydesign]` anyone?

Comment: A rounding error in integer math? That's a new one.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You start with 1 reputation point... can you add 100 and 1?

Comment: Is it **1001?**

Comment: Yes, if they're strings of course

Comment: 4+1 is 5 or 101 right? :)

Comment: @cletus: you're assuming binary.  most of us use trinary, therefore 100+1 = 101 = decimal 10.

Answer (score 0):

Related:

[Why does reputation start at 1, and have a lower bound of 1?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2621/why-does-reputation-have-a-lower-bound-of-1)