# Inconsistent relative time

Tags: bug, closed-questions, timestamps

Here's a [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/52399819/1244884) that was closed before it was asked :)

[image]

Comment: The algorithm to calculate the timestamp in the closed question banner is bugged. Reason unknown..

Comment: Maybe a rounding problem.

Comment: I've seen inconsistent rounding errors somewhere before. [Here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/31260/appropriate-data-type-for-reputation-points), [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/105920/timing-of-bounty-section-of-profile-is-off/105997#1059970), a [search for "rounding error"](https://meta.stackexchange.com/search?q=rounding+error).

Comment: I'm 100.2% sure it's a rounding error.