# Could someone have negative reputation on Stack Overflow?

Tags: support, reputation

Imagine I'm new to Stack Overflow and I create a new question that receives 10 downvotes. That means I should lose 10 x 2 reputation points.

Since a user starts with 1 rep on Stack Overflow, I understand I would have -19 rep. Is this so, or can a user's reputation never go below 0?

Comment: Related: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2621/why-does-reputation-have-a-lower-bound-of-1

Comment: Related: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/135854?tab=reputationhistory#tab-top

Comment: @Jon - truly impressive.

Comment: @Jon - that's why we **should** have negative rep :)

Comment: @jon, stop feeding him, trolls feed on attention

Comment: (@comment notification fail, wanted to alert the other @jon, @seigel?)

Comment: @Dow: I know. ...but "if it gets a laugh, leave it in." :D

Answer (score 5):

Reputation indeed never goes below 1. But the reputation graph history can. [Here was an example](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/135854?tab=reputationhistory#tab-top), but the user doesn't exist anymore.

Comment: Note also that his total official rep is greater than one in spite of everything.

Answer (score 4):

Reputation never goes below 1, no matter how much you're downvoted.