# Can someone do anything when his reputation down to 0 or -1?

Tags: discussion

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why does reputation have a lower bound of 1?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2621/why-does-reputation-have-a-lower-bound-of-1)

When someone signup SO, he only hava 1 reputation. then he posted a question ot answer, but unfortunately, he earned a down vote. according to the "Users lose reputation" in [How does reputation work](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7237/how-does-reputation-work), his reputation will become -1.

the one needs at least 1 reputation to post a question or answer, so it seems he can do nothing in SO. Is it that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Reputation [doesn't go below 1](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2621/why-does-reputation-have-a-lower-bound-of-1/2625#2625):

> The StackOverflow team believes that everybody's special in their own way and doesn't deserve to have a negative self-esteem (aka reputation).

<sup>— Jeff Atwood</sup>

Comment: that's will prevent zombie accounts appear.

Comment: Wait, my rep == my self esteem? AWESOME!

Comment: rep has nothing to do with self esteem, I think.

Comment: @Roy Really? Then why do I only feel good inside when I get upvotes?