# I can see my reputation "increasing" even though I am suspended

Tags: bug, reputation, top-bar, account-suspension, achievements-dialog

So I got myself suspended, for being an idiot.  My fault.

I now have 1 reputation.  But while I was sitting on the front page of the site where I'm suspended, somebody upvoted one of my answers.  I then appeared on the top bar to have 11 reputation.  Of course, clicking on my profile revealed that I have only 1 rep, as I should until the suspension ends.

I realize this is an incredibly minor bug, with no meaningful impact.  But the software tester in me couldn't let it go unreported.

Comment: @Oded: I think this question is asking about the Top Bar™. While on suspension, voting one of your answers shouldn't cause the top bar to show "+10", but now it does. (That's just my guess -- if that's not the case, then it could be considered as a duplicate of [this one](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/91627/why-do-suspended-users-have-a-reputation-of-one?rq=1), but I'm not sure.)

Comment: @AmalMurali - Took me a second reading to figure that out.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion, yes, on the top bar.  Question updated.

Comment: Think I found a better title, @Flimzy you can roll it back if you think otherwise. Also added the relevant tags as it's a problem in the achievements and reputation dialog box of the top bar. Also, adding a screenshot will be a good idea, though in this case not that needed, just a bonus. :)

Comment: I would add a screen shot if I could take one... but after I clicked my network profile, of course, I lost the relevant opportunity.

Comment: If someone wants to upvote one of my posts on Travel.SE, I can grab a screen shot :)

Comment: The reputation indicator also shows the -1 / +1 that comes from downvoting answers and their subsequent deletions, but clicking the reputation icon doesn't show these reputational changes.

Comment: Totally tangential: I *love* it when people can take a 'negative' situation and take positive actions in relation to it. I'd bet that UI issues for suspended users don't get many bug reports! ;)

Comment: @AndrewBarber: It would seem you are right about the low number of [UI issue reports for suspended users](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/bug+account-suspension).

Comment: According to [this answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/104355/353011) it's unlikely that this will get fixed any time soon (further supported by this question here being 5 years old).