# Can a bounty be awarded to a temporarily suspended user?

Tags: support, bounties, account-suspension

I posted a bounty on Stack Overflow and got an answer from a user that has since been temporarily suspended.

Will the system allow me to award the bounty to that user? [A Day in the Penalty Box](https://stackoverflow.blog/2009/04/06/a-day-in-the-penalty-box/) says that the user's reputation is "locked" to one.   I'm not sure if awarding the bounty is even possible.

If I can award the bounty, will the user get the reputation when their suspension is over?  [Why do suspended users have a reputation of one?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/91627/why-do-suspended-users-have-a-reputation-of-one) says that reputation from upvotes won't be seen until the suspension is over, maybe the same is true of bounties.   [I can see my reputation “increasing” even though I am suspended](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/223193/i-can-see-my-reputation-increasing-even-though-i-am-suspended) says that a suspended user can see alerts about reputation changes even though their displayed rep doesn't appear to change from 1.

Based on this I'm leaning towards awarding the bounty.  The user would be able to see the reputation after the suspension is over.  Is that correct?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes. You can award it.

It will be shown in the achievements tab of the user but still the users rep will be shown as 1.

The bounty score will be shown in [reputation history in activity tab](https://stackoverflow.com/users/current/?tab=reputation)

After the end of suspension, their reputation will be recalculated and **it will include the bounty score** and other reputation earned in the suspension period.

*All reputation changes in the suspension period will be stored as usual. The suspension limits the user from participating on the site other than visiting and the rep will be locked to 1 and no badges will be shown in their user card*