# Should a persons reputation start on 0?

Tags: discussion, reputation

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why does reputation have a lower bound of 1?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2621/why-does-reputation-have-a-lower-bound-of-1)

Why does a person start on 1 reputation? Why not 0? It can confuse the calculation of reputation points.

Comment: How can it confuse the calculation?

Comment: You get 1 point for breathing.

Comment: "There are two hard things in computer science: cache invalidation, naming things, and off-by-one errors."

Comment: Meh, let's scrap the whole thing and switch to a scoring system based on dice rolls. Upvotes are 2d6 +modifers, stave off downvotes with saving throws, etc.

Comment: And also, why can't you have a reputation lower than 1?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

No, it can't start at 0.

See the problem is we're not very good programmers, and the divide by 0 errors were absolutely killing us, so 1 is the minimum.

Comment: but answers start on 0... jks

Comment: so, that might be why negative reputations don't happen?

Comment: @iphonemaniac - When reputation reaches 0 we get errors again, so we stop before it gets there...that's why it never gets to negative either.

Comment: You'll be singing a different tune when Jon Skeet overflows the rep column in the database

Comment: Heh, and I always thought it was a psychological thing, as in "We give you one point for free, so that you don't have to feel like you're a zero."