# 500rep-500rep=?

Tags: discussion, reputation, bounties

Suppose that one has 500 reputation, and then devotes 500 reputation for a bounty.

**Question**: How much reputation remains? 0 or 1?

Remark: If this were a exercise in primary school, then anyone could easily answer 500-500=0. However, according to [this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2621/why-does-reputation-have-a-lower-bound-of-1), the minimum reputation one can have is 1, so 1 seems a possible answer too.

Comment: I don't think the system would allow you to put a bounty of 500. Otherwise Stack Exchange maths say, 500rep - 500rep = 1rep. FYI, one gets the [privilege to add bounty](http://stackoverflow.com/privileges/set-bounties) at 75 reputation.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can't. You'd need 501 rep to be able to set that high a bonus.

Comment: OMG! This answer attracted 13 Upvotes till now. If only did I add my comment as an answer. I was 15 seconds faster :-)