# Remove or change "0 reputation" tooltip from usernames in comments when a user does not exist

Tags: feature-request, comments, tooltips, deleted-accounts

When moving mouse over a username that does not exist (for example, because of deletion or migration), the tooltip "0 reputation" is displayed:

> [image]

However, since [reputation cannot be less than 1](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2621/why-does-reputation-have-a-lower-bound-of-1), the tooltip is inconsistent. For non-existing users, it should be either removed or changed to something more descriptive.

What should the text of the tooltip be? Or should it be removed altogether?

Comment: "User does not exist". That's all. Everybody can interpret their own.

Comment: I would just not show any tooltip. The name is gray and not a link, it should be obvious that it's a deleted/nonexistent user.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The tooltip appears to be gone. HTML now looks like:

```
<span class="comment-user">deleted-user-name-there</span>
```

(`title="0 reputation"` was causing this popup, now this attribute is removed).

Answer (score 0):

In cases like this, tooltip should be:

> reputation not available

It's true, it's consistent with documentation and with facts, and it requires almost no coding. Why it's not available is not really significant there, if someone will ever want to investigate, there are other ways.

Comment: 'Not available' sounds like 'it exists but cannot be accessed at the moment', whereas a lot of the time it just doesn't exist in the first place. Not that I think this is a major issue (in fact, I don't see any issue with `0 reputation` as it confuses no one), but this would confuse me more than 0 reputation would.

Comment: @jmac I don't quite understand how "not available" is supposed to be synonym of "is deleted" for you. As far as I understand, it means only "it can't be accessed for whatever reason" and says nothing about previous or future state, and about reasons.

Comment: It isn't a synonym of 'is deleted'. My issue was that 'unavailable' implies a temporary condition (if it is permanently unavailable, it would be specified as deleted). This would most frequently happen if a user is deleted, or if a question was migrated to a site where the user doesn't have an account -- neither really fits 'unavailable' and that is more confusing that just showing `zero reputation`.

Comment: @jmac if question is migrated, then it *is* a temporary condition - will cease to be when user will register at target site, as far as I know - then his rep will be shown properly.

Comment: @jmac as @nicael has said, this has been completed - can you add the [tag:status-completed] tag to this question please? I flagged this question last month (not seeing you were a mod) but it's still `pending` :)

Answer (score -1):

Why not directly show

```
User Has been removed/deleted/transfered
```

or

```
User Burninated :)
```

Comment: @MM. people will expect to see greater than 1 rep points and sometimes would cause confusion for zero rep scores that's why i suggested to implicitly tell that the user is not existing.

Comment: The most common time I see this message is when a question is migrated to a site where the person asking doesn't have an account. In that case, all these messages would be incorrect as they imply the account existed at some time in the past.

Comment: @jmac Right..take a classic [example here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/202887/how-to-get-alert-when-new-questions-posted-on-stackover-flow/202888#comment645622_202888).. In here the user created account after the answer was migrated, so "0 reputation" sounds inappropriate here..

Comment: why donwvote? weird -_-

Answer (score -2):

*Existing* users can't have zero rep and the rule says nothing about non-existing or removed users. Therefore, setting zero rep for non-existing users is not inconsistent. So, `0 reputation` is not too bad.

If someone insist that *zero* is not a valid rep anyway, this suggestion is useful, by hovering mouse over username we expect to see something related to reputation and also we like same format for all messages (`X reputation`). Then, I suggest this message which has minor changes:

> No reputation