# How to get an alert when new questions are posted on Stack Overflow?

Tags: support, tags, notifications

I am new to Stack Overflow. Now I am working as an iPhone programmer. I want to develop my skill in [Objective-C](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Objective-C) and iOS. How do I get alerts, when new questions are posted with tags related to Objective-C and iOS?

Comment: I need notifications in my stackoverflow account, when new question posted related to ios and Objective-c.. I see both link from this how can I done this?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can subscribe to the Objective-C tag easily. Just hover mouse on the 'objective-c' tag and you will see this:

> [image]

Click on the subscribe button to receive notifications on new questions posted using that tag.

Comment: Thank you so much. now I got it.....

Comment: please feel free to mark my post as answer if I helped you.. Thanks :)

Comment: Can I get alert in stackoverlow page on recent inbox message icon or somewhere else without opening the message box?

Comment: Is there any way to subscribe not just to tags but to particular search terms (the message body should also be searched, automatically) which are not particularly tags? Tags are quite common, while some specific terms may not be tags.

Comment: @MaximMasiutin I'm searching for the same thing, any luck?

Comment: @CaffeinateOften Any update on a solution?

Comment: The UI seems to have changed. I can now "watch" tags, but I don't seem to be getting any notifications as a result of doing this.