# How this user got 10 reputation?

Tags: discussion, bug, reputation, questions, users

I saw [this user](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3082314/flanker-42) got [ten reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3082314/flanker-42?tab=reputation) from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20467907/c-sharp-convert-grayscale-data-to-colored-image), but the question was put on hold and the user got one downvote from it. How could he get ten reputation from it?

Comment: 2 upvotes after the 3 downvotes

Comment: You can't get negative rep.  If the upvotes are after the downvotes he will get the 10 rep

Comment: Indeed the question is terrible. I've just downvoted it.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

When the user has only 1 rep the downvotes don't change anything. So when the 2 upvotes were applied, it became 11.

```
1   -2 1
1   -2 1
1   -2 1
1   +5 6
6   +5 11
```

Comment: It should be a bug?

Comment: Not necessarily. Can also be a design decision.

Answer (score 5):

The downvotes happened before the upvotes, so he didn't lose any reputation from it ([you can't have negative reputation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2621/why-does-reputation-have-a-lower-bound-of-1)).

[image]

Comment: But doesn't he then lose the reputation still from the downvotes?

Comment: Apparently not.

Comment: @Me123: No, because you cannot go below a reputation of 1.

Comment: Apparently the algorithm doesn't apply the rep in retrospect. Probably for performance reasons or the algorithm becoming more complex. You would have to recalculate the rep every time for the history.

Answer (score -3):

Reputation is floored at 1. So a new user will gain net positive reputation if downvotes are followed by upvotes even if, in normal circumstances, it would have the net effect of decreasing reputation.

Personally I think **the floor is flawed**: it can artificially inflate new-user reputation due to sympathetic upvoting.

Look at, for example, what you can do with 15 rep: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges

Comment: I disagree. How much can you really inflate this way. To 10 or 20? Won't make a big difference. Starting on SO is not easy and at least you are not punished for mistakes too severely.