# Will past downvoted questions affect current reputation points if you only have 1 reputation point?

Tags: discussion, reputation

I have had this question for some time now.

For example:
I currently have only 1 rep point.

If I ask a question and receive a lot of downvotes, this will not *currently* affect my reputation (since my rep is only 1 point).

But then, *in the future,* if I get more reputation points, then will the downvoted question affect my current reputation?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No. Reputation lost when you have only one reputation point will never be accounted for. So, when you earn additional reputation, you will be free and clear. This is noted in the [Reputation FAQ](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/7238/284336):

> No user’s reputation may drop below one point; if an action would cause a user’s reputation to drop below one point, that user only loses enough reputation to drop to one point ([source](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2621/why-does-reputation-have-a-lower-bound-of-1)), and the remaining penalty or loss is waived.

Comment: Doesn't this promote sockpuppeting for discussion of unpopular opinions? Is sockpuppeting prevalent on SE?

Comment: @Dagelf You do see this on Politics and Skeptics, but it's more like trolling than actual discussion. A 1-rep account will pop up and post a low-quality, bad-faith question, it'll get heavily downvoted and deleted, then a week later a different 1-rep account will pop up and post a slightly different version of the exact same question... rinse and repeat *ad nauseum*.

Comment: That is where IP bans come in @F1Krazy

Comment: Are you saying downvotes (on non-deleted posts) when at one reputation point are forgotten?